# Autoplay function for a basic jquery slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, slider

I would like to add an autoplay feature that automatically rotates the slides every 4 seconds or so and was wondering how I would go about adding that functionality to my current slider(code below):

*UPDATE* added current code which has slider autorotating and in the right direction, but the navigation arrows don't work anymore.

Thanks!

**HTML:**

```
<div id='top_slider' >
    <div id='container' >
        <?php $dots=0;$posts=query_posts('category_name=slider-feature');
        if ( have_posts() ): while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slider_vimeo_id', true)!==""): ?>
                <div style="left: 0%;" class="slide">
                    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slider_vimeo_id', true); ?>" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
                </div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div style="left: 100%;" class="slide">
                    <a href='<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slider_link_url', true); ?>'><img class="fullscreen_img" src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slider_image_url', true); ?>"></a>
                </div>
    </div>

    <div id='slider_nav' class='inline-block'>
        <div id='center'>
            <div class="arrow_left element hot_img" onclick="slide('right')"></div>

            <?php for ($i=0; $i<$dots; $i++) { ?>
                <div class="dot element hot_img" onclick="slide(<?php echo $i ?>)"></div>
            <?php } ?>
                <div class="arrow_right element hot_img" onclick="slide('left')"></div>
        </div>
    </div>           
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function slide(dir) {
    if (slideInProgress != 0) {
        return;
    }
    slideInProgress = 3;
    var current, next, nextSlide;
    current = jQuery(slides[currentSlideIndex]);
    if (!isNaN(dir)) {
        next = dir;
        if (next > currentSlideIndex)
            dir = 'left';
        else
            dir = 'right';
    }
    ;
    if (dir == 'left') {
        if (!next) {
            next = currentSlideIndex + 1;
            if (next >= slides.length) {
                next = 0;
            }
        }
        nextSlide = jQuery(slides[next]);
        nextSlide.css('left', '100%');
        nextSlide.css('z-index', parseInt(current.css('z-index'), 10) + 1);
        //nextSlide.animate({left: '0%'}, 1500);
        nextSlide.animate({
            left: '0%'
        }, {
            duration: 1500,
            complete: function() {
                slideInProgress--;
            }
        });
        //current.animate({left: '-100%'}, 1500);
        current.animate({
            left: '-100%'
        }, {
            duration: 1500,
            complete: function() {
                slideInProgress--;
            }
        });

    } else {
        console.log('moving right');
        if (!next) {
            next = currentSlideIndex - 1;
            if (next < 0) {
                next = slides.length - 1;
            }
        }
        nextSlide = jQuery(slides[next]);
        nextSlide.css('left', '-100%');
        nextSlide.css('z-index', parseInt(current.css('z-index'), 10) + 1);
        //nextSlide.animate({left: '0%'}, 1500);
        nextSlide.animate({
            left: '0%'
        }, {
            duration: 1500,
            complete: function() {
                slideInProgress--;
            }
        });
        //current.animate({left: '100%'}, 1500);
        current.animate({
            left: '100%'
        }, {
            duration: 1500,
            complete: function() {
                slideInProgress--;
            }
        });

    }
    current.addClass('active');
    nextSlide.removeClass('active');
    var el = jQuery('.dot:eq(' + currentSlideIndex + ')');
    src = el.css("background-image").replace("_over", "_off");
    el.css("background-image", src);
    el.removeClass('active');
    el = jQuery('.dot:eq(' + next + ')');
    src = el.css("background-image").replace("_off", "_over");
    el.css("background-image", src);
    el.addClass('active');
    console.log('currentSlideIndex' + currentSlideIndex);
    console.log('next' + next);
    console.log('dir' + dir);
    currentSlideIndex = next;
    // **** //
    slideInProgress--;
    // **** //
}

setInterval(function() {slide('left')}, 6000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

move your slide function out of **setInterval** and call the function with it. this way the calls to the function in the onclick attribute of your elements will work too:

```
function slide(dir) {
//the content of function
}

setInterval(function(){ slide(dir); }, 4000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that sort of worked. After 4 seconds it will switch from the first slide to the last slide but then it stops sliding. I'm guessing it's because the function allows it to slide left or right depending on the arrow button the user clicks. Is there a way to make it so that it only automates the slide(right) function?

Comment: Ok I got it working by changing "function slide(dir)" to:

window.setInterval(function slide(dir) {

}, 4000)

But it's still rotating in the wrong direction.

Comment: @APAD1 oppps my bad I have suggested setting interval but I have set timeout, I corrected my answer.

Comment: @APAD1 if you write your html code too we can help better. you can write your code in jsfiddle.net and give us a link.

Comment: I have added my HTML code to the initial post. Thanks again! Also, currently it's setup so that the dots are clickable for navigation as well, but now that it's autoplaying, I just need the arrows to be clickable.

Comment: I have edited the answer, by the way if it helped please choose as answer and vote up

Comment: Thanks, I got it! Updated my original code in case anyone else can gain anything from this.